# How to change/return the value of editing to false in subchild in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***parent.ts***

```
editing = true;
```

***parent.html***

```
<div [editing]="editing"></div>
```

***child.ts***

```
@Input editing: any;

editLayout(room?: any, rows?: any) {
    this.modalRef = this.modal.create({
      nzContent: RoomEditorComponent,
      nzMaskClosable: true,
      nzClosable: false,
      nzWidth: '99%',
      nzClassName: 'action-form room-editor-modal',
      nzComponentParams: {
        data: {
          room: room
          rows: rows
        },
        editing: this.editing
      },
      nzFooter: null
    });
```

What I tried is
***child.ts***

```
   @Input editing: any;
    
    editLayout(room?: any, rows?: any) {
        this.modalRef = this.modal.create({
          nzContent: RoomEditorComponent,
          nzMaskClosable: true,
          nzClosable: false,
          nzWidth: '99%',
          nzClassName: 'action-form room-editor-modal',
          nzComponentParams: {
            data: {
              room: room
              rows: rows
            },
            editing: this.editing
          },
          nzFooter: null
        });
```

***sub-child.ts***

```
@Input editing;

saveRoom() {
 this.editing = false;
}
```

How to return the editing to false in sub-child.

cause what I did is when I save the Room it doesn't return or change the value of editing to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make changes to the input value after it's been passed from the component you can use an input setter method to assign it to another variable which you have more control over, e.g.

```
@Input() set editing(editing:boolean){
  this._editing = editing
}
private _editing:boolean
```

Then you can use the `_editing` variable within the sub-child.

If you additionally want to notify up to the parent, then you could either add an event, service, or local variable to allow 2-way communication. See examples of all of these at: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction. I would personally say for a single change output events might be the easiest, you can see another specific example here: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding